# Insertion Sort in a Class?

Tags: c++, class, insertion-sort

I'm a Cpp newbie and I have a question that i can't find an answer to it. So Im writing this program about Tourist sights using a class. Inside i have name of the sight, addres and distance from the city center. All i've done is the input and output. Now i have no idea how to sort them with InsertionSort. Do I need another array?
I want to sort them by distance but have no idea how to write it.

Here is what i have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Tobekt {
  private: string name;
          string addres;
          int distance;


  public:
    void input(void);
    void output(void);
}; 

void Tobekt::input(){

   cout<<"Landmark name: ";
   getline(cin, name);
   getline(cin, addres);
   cout<<"Addres: "; 
    getline(cin, addres);
    cout<<"Distance from the city center:  ";
    cin>>distance;
}
void Tobekt::output(){
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Landmark name: "<<name<<endl;
   cout<<"Addres: "<<addres<<endl; 
    cout<<"Distance from the city center: "<<distance<<endl;

}

int main()
    { 
    int n;
    cout<<"Tourist landmarks:" ;
    cin>>n;
    Tobekt *A = new Tobekt[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        A[i].input();
    }
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        A[i].output();
    }

return 0;
    }
```

Comment: use a `std::vector`. `new` without `delete` is a memory leak. `new` with `delete` is still a potential memory leak. You dont need any manual memory managment here

Comment: *Now i have no idea how to sort them with InsertionSort.*  -- You didn't show any attempt, and we have no idea what type of help you are asking for (you're not asking a focused question).  Anyway [here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply sort the array using the `sort` algorithm that you have in the standard library and provinding a custom sorting criteria. In the following for instance the sights are sorted by distance.

```
auto sort_criteria=[](const auto& a, const auto&b){
return a.distance < b.distance;
};

int main()
    { 
      Tobekt *A = new Tobekt[n];
      //read input
       sort(A, A+n, sort_criteria);
      //other stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Insertion Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)'s algorithm do not require a new array for sorting. The idea behind insertion sort is to loop through the array twice.

- First Loop is to loop through the "unsorted" elements in the array and pick the first "unsorted" element.
- Second Loop is to compare that element with the previous "sorted" elements - if its "smaller", move the element towards your start of the array index and repeat until it cannot be moved.

You can visit this [link](https://visualgo.net/bn/sorting) to get a better visualization of how it works. As such, you may need a function that performs the comparison function. Something like...

```
bool SmallerDistance(const Tobekt& lhs, const Tobekt& rhs)
{
    return lhs.GetDistance() < rhs.GetDistance();
}
```

Of course, you would need to create getter function to get the distance from the class. Alternatively, you could always create the `operator<` member function and compare with two variables.

P.S. Do remember to delete A variable after you `new` or you will have memory leak for your program.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the book of [R. Lafore "Algorithms & Data Structures in Java"](https://github.com/sagar9268/PPLAB/blob/master/Data%20Structures%20%26%20Algorithms%20in%20Java%20-%20Robert%20Lafore.pdf) useful. There are two chapters on sorting algorithms including insertion sort with relevant code snippets. (It says Java, but the syntax in Java is close to C++, and there's a section in the book that discusses differences between the two languages.)